# Installing packages with pip with multiple python installs

Tags: python, windows, pip, anaconda

I have been using Anaconda python on Windows 7, but a package I need isn't supported by Anaconda python, so I installed CPython from python.org. I'd like to install the package to CPython, but `pip` still installs everything to `C:\Anaconda\ ...\site-packages`. How can I change this?

Comment: Just use pip from the target Python installation. You can run the module itself using -m, e.g. `C:\Python27\python.exe -m pip install [package]`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I imagine this will work, but having tried it I've realized some things must have gone wrong with my python install. There is no scripts folder in C:\Python27. I seem to be experiencing the same issue as seen in this post http://bugs.python.org/issue23604 which I'm now working to resolve. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your `PATH` environment variable to put `C:\PythonXX\Scripts` (where `XX` is the version of Python, usually `27` or `34`) at the beginning.

Click on **`My Computer -> Properties -> System Properties -> Advanced -> Environment Variables`**, then select `Path` in either the **`System Variables`** section (if you have Administrator access), or **`User Variables`** if you don't. Click <kbd>Edit</kbd> and put the correct path at the beginning, followed by a semi-colon `;`. Save everything, close your command line session(s), then start a new one. Running `pip -V` should now print the CPython version and location instead of the Anaconda one.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Anaconda installed, an easier way to modify your PATH is to use the `activate` and `deactivate` scripts.

```
activate envname
```

will put the `envname` environment on your PATH, and

```
deactivate
```

will remove it.

Hence, you just need to call `activate` before calling `pip`.